# How to store and call web API by name?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, aspnetboilerplate

I want to save the name of API to the database and call it after that. How can i do that?

Example:

I want to save the name of these APIs (`Action1`, `Action2` and `Action3`) into the database and call it when I need (because I want to reorder or delete some actions in the UI):

```
public interface IMyAppService : IApplicationService
    {
        Task Action1();
        Task Action2(); 
        Task Action3();          
    }
```

So how can I store the API name as string in database and how to execute it after that? Should I store them like this?

```
"http://localhost/api/services/mpa/myApp/Action1"
"http://localhost/api/services/mpa/myApp/Action2"
"http://localhost/api/services/mpa/myApp/Action3"
```

Comment: you have 2 options: either save it by url or by controller name and then use reflection. depends on how are you going to call them afterwards

Comment: which is the better solution, bro?

Comment: again, how are you going to call them later? and where from? but from questions, seems like saving urls and call them through `HttpClient` is safest solution to start with.

Comment: Thank bro, I will use this solution.

Comment: I have found the answer in my other question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091480/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-a-api-by-string-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091480/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-a-api-by-string-name)

Comment: It was resolved, I have added a reference to your answer in another question. :)

Comment: I posted an answer to wrap up this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. save it by URL + use `HttpClient`, or

   - Pro: Transaction rollback is handled by ABP framework when an exception is thrown.
   - Con: You need to handle web request, authorization and deserialization of response.
2. save it by AppService and method names + use reflection.

   - Pro: Authorization is handled by ABP framework when in `IAbpSession.Use()` block.
   - Con: You may need to handle transactions and exceptions ⇒ logic leaks to the caller.

---

For completeness sake, this question is the first of a series of other Stack Overflow questions:

1. This question. (Oct 23)
2. [How to call Web API (App Service) remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026840/how-to-call-web-api-app-service-remotely) (Oct 31) — Option 1
3. [How to call web API under specific user permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031071/how-to-call-web-api-under-specific-user-permission) (Oct 31) — Option 1, switch to Option 2
4. [How to use reflection to call a API by string name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091480/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-a-api-by-string-name) (Nov 3) — Option 2

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use Audit ??

You can easly track all application interaction (so even calls to your service) into AbpAuditLogs table using

[ABP Audit Documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Audit-Logging?searchKey=Audit)

Comment: I want to create a table to define all my APIs at the beginning and use it for other purposes, bro.