# How to call Web API (App Service) remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, aspnetboilerplate

I need to call an API from AppService by uri.

This is my API:

```
public ApiOutputBase Test_AddStudent(string name, int age, string address)
{
     return new ApiOutputBase
     {
          Result = new Result { Status = true, Message = "OK,Test_AddStudent Done!" },
          OuputValues = new List<object>() { name, age, address }
     };
}
```

I use this Function to call it:

```
public async Task<bool> TestCallApi()
{
     var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/") };
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

     var testJson = "{\r\n    \"name\": \"MyName\",\r\n    \"age\": 25,\r\n    \"address\": \"MyAddress\"\r\n}";
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/services/myApp/commonLookup/Test_AddStudent", new StringContent(testJson));

     // Call api success
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
     }

     return true;
}
```

I used Swagger to call `Test_AddStudent` successfully. The `testJson` was copied from Swagger when I call `Test_AddStudent` successfully.

After that, I used Swagger to call `TestCallApi` without any error, but when I tried to debug the value of `HttpResponseMessage`, it showed this error:

```
{
    StatusCode: 400,
    ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request',
    Version: 1.1,
    Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
    Headers: {
        Pragma: no-cache
        Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
        Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 02:12:45 GMT
        Set-Cookie: Abp.Localization.CultureName=en; expires=Thu, 31-Oct-2019 02:12:45 GMT; path=/
        Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
        X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
        X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
        Content-Length: 405
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
        Expires: -1
    }
}
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Show your error log.

Comment: It already in my post, bro. Should I add anything for authorization?

Comment: That's a HTTP response. Show your error log that's in `*.Web.Mvc\App_Data\Logs`.

Comment: I tried to run this function many times but could not find any related log. Note: I use swagger to call this function

Comment: Swagger? Aren't you having an error with `HttpClient` as in your question?

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clearly, bro

Comment: "when I tried to debug the variable response" → What does that even mean?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, that is the value of "HttpResponse"

Comment: If you don't provide an error log, we won't know why it's a `Bad Request`.

Comment: Thank bro, it is also my problem :(, I will try to find it.

Comment: Check `*.Web.Host\App_Data\Logs`.

Comment: I have run that function many times but the log file didn't change. I tried to call another test api (mockapi.io) and it worked so that i think the error was come from Authorization

Comment: Thank for your help, Aaron. I found the issue that I pass the wrong input in the request. :)

Comment: No problem. If your solution is worth sharing, describe it in an answer.

Comment: Already share the solution for me. But now I faced the new issue: how to authenticate the HttpClient, bro?

Comment: Use `client.SetBearerToken(accessToken)`. [Ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you tried that and need further help.

Comment: Thank, I just create a new topic. Could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031071/how-to-call-web-api-under-specific-user-permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root cause: I passed the wrong input to the api:

Wrong:

```
var testJson = "{\r\n    \"name\": \"MyName\",\r\n    \"age\": 25,\r\n    \"address\": \"MyAddress\"\r\n}";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/services/myApp/commonLookup/Test_AddStudent", new StringContent(testJson));
```

Correct:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/services/myApp/commonLookup/Test_AddStudent?name=MyName&age=25&address=MyAdress", "");
```