# How to call web API under specific user permission?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, aspnetboilerplate

I have a function that allows the end user to execute a `Workflow` (containing many APIs) or schedule it to run as a background job.

Example: `User1` creates `Workflow1`, which contains 3 APIs (`Api1`, `Api2`, `Api3`), and configures it to run at 9AM every day.

I use `HttpClient` to call each API like this:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/") };
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/services/myApp/workflow/Api1?input=something", "").Result;
```

How do I add the credentials of `User1` to the request while the user is not logged in to the application (because it will run automatically as a scheduled job)?

## Update 1

I decided to [use reflection to call an API by string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091480/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-a-api-by-string-name).

In the case of executing an API directly, how do I run it under a specific permission?

## Update 2

I have put my code inside a `using` block, but all APIs were fired successfully:

```cs
using (_session.Use(1, 3)) // 3 is the Id of User1, who has no permissions
{
    // Execute operator
    switch (input.Operator.Type)
    {
        case "api":
            executeApiResult = await ExecuteApi(input);
            break;
        case "procedure":
            executeApiResult = await ExecuteProcedure(input);
            break;
        default:
            return new ExecuteOperatorOutput
            {
                Result = new ExecuteOperatorResult { Status = false, Message = $"Wrong operator type: {input.Operator.Type}" },
                WorkflowStatus = false
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the case of executing an API directly, how do I run it under a specific permission?

You can [override current session values](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Abp-Session#overriding-current-session-values) and call your method inside the `using` block.

> I have put my code inside a `using` block, but all APIs were fired successfully

Declare your API methods as `public virtual` as there are some restrictions for [`AbpAuthorize`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization#abpauthorize-attribute-notes).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1- You can make those Application Services anonymously accessible. And if you want it to be secure, send an encrypted security token.

2- You didn't mention if your project is MVC or Angular. I assume you have Angular version. You need a bearer token to make authenticated requests. First you have to authenticate user and get a token. Then add this bearer token to every request.

You have to research for using bearer tokens in asp.net core...

Comment: My project is MVC in asp.net 4.6.1. Could i use bearer token?

Comment: For MVC you can't use bearer token. You need to make cookie authentication.  After you make login request. You'll get response cookies. What you have to do is; add these cookies to your requests. If I remember correctly cookies must be ASP.NET_SessionId
.AspNet.ApplicationCookie

Comment: The solution is not a couple of lines code. So I can't provide you a full code solution.

Comment: Thank you, but how to get the cookies without user login? I need to run the workflow as a scheduled job.

Comment: I think you are on wrong way. You cannot authenticate users without credentials. Why don't you just ignore authenticating! Simple solution; make anonymous authentication services. Add a security token which you can decrypt and check to proceed.Don't authenticate, just send token, userId and other params to app service method.

Comment: will consider your solution, is there any way to create the credentials directly? I will call to those api in the same app.